# In Excel, how can I add values from two "vectors" sorted by rank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel like this is actually a quite simple problem but I couldn't find a way to word it in a good way and so I haven't found an answer yet.

Basically, in an Excel sheet, I have 4 calculated values (let's say A1:D1). Meanwhile, I have a fixed vector of 4 other values (10, -20, -40, -50).
I'm looking for an efficient way of adding 10 to the biggest value of A1:D1, -20 to the second biggest value of A1:D1, -40 to the third and -50 to the last.

My current solution is rather ugly. For each of my four calculated values, I have `=<calculation>+IF(RANK(A1,A1:D1)=1,10,IF(RANK(A1,A1:D1)=2,-20,IF(RANK(A1,A1:D1)=3,-40,-50)))`

Comment: You say "let's say A1:D1", though vector-type may matter here. Is your array of fixed values also a horizontal vector, e.g. A2:D2? And what should the result be? A further horizontal vector (in A3:D3?)?

Comment: Wouldn't the `LARGE` function solve your issue? Excel's `LARGE` function gives you the k-th largest number of a array or range of values.

Comment: Currently my A1:D1 vector is horizontal. My fixed values can be stored anywhere, maybe in another sheet. Result can be stored in another vector but I'd like to directly affect the initial vector A1:D1, for "aesthetic" purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use LARGE with RANK returning the `k` value.

```
=LARGE($G$1:$G$4,RANK(A1,$A$1:$D$1))*A1
```

[image]